# Event in Javascript to tieHTML Update to

Tags: javascript, html

I am fixing a classic ASP program to allow Content Security Policy
A calendar popup which is mostly built in javascript needs click events to work
forward and back through the months - and setting a textbox on clicking a day
the body of the control is

```
<body leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" >
    <div class="calendardiv" id="calendar2"></div>
</body>
```

a javascript file added in the  element puts together the elements

```
    var output = '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="calendar_table">';
            
    output += '<tr class="header color_1_3">';
    output +=   '<td><a ID="BACK" class="mod_head_link" href="#" ><<</a></td>';
    output +=   '<td colspan="5" class="mod_head_text">' + strMonth.toUpperCase() + ", " + nYear + '</td>';
    output +=   '<td><a ID="FORWARD" class="mod_head_link" href="#" >>></a></td>';
    output += '</tr>';
    output += '</table>';
    return output;
```

and sets it to calendardiv.InnerHTML
this snippet executes when the control pops up the first time

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    loadCalendar();
    set_event_handlers();
}, false);
```

the set_event_handlers is as follows:

```
function set_event_handlers()
{
    var back_obj = document.getElementById("BACK");
    if (back_obj == null) { }
    else
    {
        back_obj.addEventListener("click", function () {
            back("mo");
        }, false);
    }

    var forward_obj = document.getElementById("FORWARD");
    if (forward_obj == null) { }
    else
    {
        forward_obj.addEventListener("click", function () {
            forward_obj("mo");
        }, false);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        vDay_obj = document.getElementById(i);
        if (vDay_obj == null)
        {
            vDay_obj = document.getElementById("today");
        }
        if (vDay_obj == null) { alert('null'); }
        else
        {
            vDay_obj.addEventListener("click", function () {
                showDate(this);
            }, false);
            vDay_obj.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
                restore(this);
            }, false);
            vDay_obj.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                hilite(this);
            }, false);
        }
    }
}
```

however
when the month is sent back or forward the events are no longer triggered
loadCalendar(); is not necessary
how would I trigger to run the set_event_handlers after the calendardiv gets all new elements?
what event - and where would I set the code to trigger it

Comment: so sounds like you need to rebind the events. You do not show the code for the back

Comment: `back("mo");  set_event_handlers();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you are rebuilding the entire HTML which replaces your back/forward links with new ones. Which means the event handlers won't work as they were tied to the previous element.

Instead of adding the event handler to the individual elements, I would simply delegate the event handler to the document.body and check to see if the element clicked has a specific ID then run the appropriate function.

This way you only have to do it once and new events / updated calendar won't affect the event handlers.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    let target = e.target;
    if(target.id == "BACK"){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("BACK");
    }
    else if(target.id == "FORWARD"){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("FORWARD");
    }
});
```

```html
<a id="BACK" href="#">BACK</a>
<a id="FORWARD" href="#">FORWARD</a>
```